# i want all nodes of level which i node i am passing in start with clause

Tags: database, oracle, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, sql-query-store

Suppose following is hierarchy:
[image]

I am passing **5**, so i am excepting 5,4,2,1 so how can I do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 4? It is not an ancestor of 5 but it is a descendant of an ancestor (2) but then why not 3 or 6 (which are also descendants of an ancestor of your start vertex)?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL for your tables and the SQL statement **YOU** have tried to use to solve the problem and what the issues are. Also, you have tagged [oracle] and [sql-query-store] which is an SQL server product - which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all ancestors and siblings of `5` then use parent id in `start with` clause:

```
/* sample data
with t(id, pid) as (
    select 1, null from dual union all
    select 2,    1 from dual union all
    select 3,    1 from dual union all
    select 4,    2 from dual union all
    select 5,    2 from dual union all
    select 6,    3 from dual ) */ 
select distinct id
  from t connect by prior pid = id
  start with pid = (select pid from t where id = 5)
```